# term_description help

Tags: custom-taxonomy

i have a piece of code which is helped to display the description of custom taxonomies
but i want to put `<h1>` tag for the title of description, but that description box doesn't takes html tags,
so how can i implement html tags to my description
here is my code

```
<div class="featured post">
                    <p><?php 
            if ( is_tax( 'location' ) ) {
                echo term_description();
            }
            elseif (is_tax('mba_courses')){
                echo term_description();
            }
            elseif (is_tax('duration')){
                echo term_description();
            }
            ?></p>


                </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

H1 tags around the descriptions?

```
echo '<h1>' . term_description() . '</h1>';
```

*UPDATE: Add link to plugin to allow HTML in term descriptions.*

**WordPress Plugins - Allow HTML in Category Descriptions**
This will work with custom taxonomies to.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/allow-html-in-category-descriptions/

**Copy of the appropriate code**
For those of you that want to simply see how it's done.

```
$filters = array('pre_term_description', 'pre_link_description', 'pre_link_notes', 'pre_user_description');
foreach ( $filters as $filter ) {
    remove_filter($filter, 'wp_filter_kses');
}

foreach ( array( 'term_description' ) as $filter ) {
    remove_filter( $filter, 'wp_kses_data' );
}
```

Comment: but this will make entire description in H1,
my description will be having something in paragraph, where i want just the title should be in h1

Comment: It wasn't clear exactly what you wanted from the information provided, but i've updated my answer with a link and some code.

Comment: If your question has been addressed please be sure to mark the answer as correct, and you're welcome... ;)